# Regex - How do I retrieve all youtube embedded block in HTML?

Tags: regex, youtube

normally, in html, youtube can be presented as

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/qvt_Ae1eRPo?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/qvt_Ae1eRPo?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

My question is that what's the regex that can retrieve this "object" block from a HTML string?

Thanks

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Please choose the appropriate library/utility depending on your framewrok and refrain yourself from using regexes for tasks such as this.

Comment: @Bohemian, what if I am sure this <object> tags are valid one, and only need this part in the whole HTML?

Comment: If you're *sure*, then it's OK. The risk is that some "web guy" changes the HTML is some weird way and your code breaks, even though the site does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/<object.+?<\/object>/mis` should work, please note that if you want a proper retrieval of HTML tags and their contents, you should really use a parser

Comment: thanks, but why? if I only need to retrieve <object>, does it matter?

Comment: if you are just looking for this particular tag, there is not object element nested inside another object and it always has the format of <object></object> AND you are only interested in retrieving the entire element, you should be ok.